Can you use transformEffect with scrollTransition in SwiftUI?
I want to create some translation effects with scrollTransition.
Here's an example using scaleEffect. I've tried using transformEffect to do translation but that modifier doesn't seem to work with scrollTransition. Is there another way to create a translation effect?
struct ContentView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .orange, .red]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundStyle(color)
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                content
                                    .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.6)
                            }
                    }
                    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 0)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    }
}


Use .offset(x:y:). Example:
struct ContentView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .orange, .red]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundStyle(color)
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                content
                                    .offset(y: phase.isIdentity ? 0 : 100)
                                    .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.6)
                                    .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                            }
                    }
                    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 1, spacing: 0)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    }
}


Thank you! Is there also a way to change the offset based on the direction you're swiping?
